# Is it possible to dual-boot with each OS on different drives?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I have an Asus UX32VD which has a 500gb HDD and a 32gb SSD. I'd like to install Ubuntu on the SSD keep the pre-installed Windows 7 on the HDD. Is this possible, and if so, how should I set up my partitions?

I currently have my boot and EFI partition on the SSD. Ubuntu works fine, but it doesn't seem to recognize the Windows install.

Comment: Please run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), then indicate the URL that will appear. It will give us valuable information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well you installed in right order, Windows first.  Does `sudo update-grub` not detect Windows partition?  I'm not really sure of all this new EFI stuff, but would recommend grub-customizer:

https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer/

Your BIOS *may* have the option to choose which disk to boot first, if you have trouble, you can always use EasyBCD from within Windows to tweak your Windows loader:

http://neosmart.net/download.php?id=1

You can either have two boot loaders installed, one for each physical disk, this has some redundancy, or choose just the one.  Hopefully those tools will help you & whip your laptop into some kinda shape!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "Ubuntu works fine, but it doesn't seem to recognize the Windows install?" Are you referring to the boot loader (GRUB 2)? Are you referring to the ability to mount the Windows partition(s) after booting Windows? Are you referring to something else? Your question is unclear, and without clarification, answers might be *way* off base!